# How to set constant in express js?

Tags: express

I want to set constant to reuse anywhere in my application. 
For example:

```
var config = require('../../config.js');
```

i want :

```
var config = require(baseUrl + '/config.js');
```

with: baseUrl = host + port

How can i do that ? 
Thanks advances!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `global` object. It's accessible everywhere in your project. The module which started node process, and all the modules included in it share the same global object.

f.e.

```
global.baseUrl = host + port;
```

in another module

```
var config = require(global.baseUrl + '/config.js');
```

Also `GLOBAL` is an alias for `global`.